# Google reCaptcha within SweetAlert modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, sweetalert

I'm working on a function which requires doing a reCaptcha verification within a SweetAlert popup box, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

I've been looking into what's causing this error, and I notice it's because the element hasn't been loaded yet when it tries to generate the reCaptcha element.

```js
function confirmBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'recaptcha';
    div.onload = genRecaptcha();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        content: div,
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
}

function genRecaptcha() {
    console.log($('#recaptcha').attr('id'));
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': '6Le2ZFUUAAAAAEV4IM_5weEnXg4gVplan2Atgiaj'
    });
}

$('#btn1').click(confirmBox);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">Submit</button>
```

I'm trying to put the `genRecaptcha` function with the `onload` trigger, but it seems to be unable to get the element.

Is there any way to execute the function after the popup box is fully loaded? Or there is something I did wrong here?

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat appreciated that, but solution of the question will been more than appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve by using `$(element).ready` from [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of using `.onload`

***code snippet provided below won't able to function properly because of the recaptcha site key is invalid for this site***

```js
function confirmBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'recaptcha';
    $('#recaptcha').ready(function () {
        console.log($('#recaptcha').attr('id'));
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '6Le2ZFUUAAAAAEV4IM_5weEnXg4gVplan2Atgiaj'
        });
    })

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        content: div,
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
}

$('#btn1').click(confirmBox);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPD**: Here's the live demo: https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/recaptcha.html

---

Here's the solution with [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) - the supported fork of SweetAlert:

```js
function showSweetAlertRecaptcha() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'SweetAlert2 + Recaptcha',
    html: '<div id="recaptcha"></div>',
    willOpen: function() {
      grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': '6LdvplUUAAAAAK_Y5M_wR7s-UWuiSEdVrv8K-tCq'
      });
    }, 
    preConfirm: function () {
      if (grecaptcha.getResponse().length === 0) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please verify that you're not a robot`)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#recaptcha > div {
  width: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=showSweetAlertRecaptcha"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: With current version 8.2.5 you should use `swal.showValidationMessage(                 'Please verify that you're not a robot')`